# QWidget delete file on destroy

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'd like to **automatically** delete a temporary file when my QWidget is destroyed (for example, at the end of the program).

I tried to handle it with the **destroyed** signal, but it doesn't work, my callback function is never executed.

Source code:

```
import sys
from os import remove
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(flags=Qt.Window)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        with open('temporary_file.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write("Hello World!")
        self.destroyed.connect(self._on_destroyed)

    @pyqtSlot(name='_on_destroyed')
    def _on_destroyed(self):
        print("Never executed.")
        remove('temporary_file.txt')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The `destroyed` signal is emitted after the python part has been removed, so your code can't catch it. Implement the [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) special Python method instead. Be sure not to throw exceptions from this method though. Alternatively, use the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module

Comment: Do you really need to delete the file when the widget is actually destroyed, rather than just on program exit?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`closeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) for this:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(flags=Qt.Window)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        with open('temporary_file.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write("Hello World!")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('close event')
        remove('temporary_file.txt')
```

Comment: closeEvent doesn't mean, that widget will be destroyed.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov. I know - that's why I said the OP **should** use it (i.e. it's the normal way to do cleanup on program exit).

Comment: A widget is not guaranteed to receive a `closeEvent` before its destructor is called.

Comment: @KubaOber. That's true - I'm assuming it's a top-level widget (as in the OPs example). Anyway, if the OP really needs to do cleanup after the widget has been destroyed, [atexit](http://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) is probably the best solution.

Comment: If you don't want to subclass a widget, or any other QObject, yet track its destruction, you should attach to its `destroyed` signal. Otherwise, you should implement a destructor, whether in C++ or Python. `atexit` is not a solution that has has anything to do with object lifetime.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the module-global reference to the widget, so `atexit` isn't guaranteed to be called *after* it's deleted in that case (I'm only talking about program exit here, not the lifetime of individual objects).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trivial: replace `_on_destroyed` with `__del__(self)`, and remove the slot annotation. That's really all there's to it.

Alas, you don't need to do that. Use a `QTemporaryFile` member and it will be automatically removed upon destruction.